# How to bypass captcha?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, captcha

I am using *gmx.com* for sending my email from MVC application but the problem is that when i send the email it ask for *captcha* which i cannot provide using code. So is their any way to by pass the *captcha* Or any general way to bypass any *captcha* from code.

the error is

```
The mail cannot be send Error:
```

if this cannot be solved then please provide me some other secure and fast Smtp server for sending mail
Thank you in advance

Comment: Gmail, easy, fast, reliable...

Comment: Our project requirement does not meet with gmail